# Magento 2: How to display Product Available QTY on checkout Order Summary

Tags: magento2, checkout, knockoutjs

I would like to know if there is any way, to show the Product(Added to cart) Available Qty in checkout page under Product's name in Order Summary Section in Magento 2.

As per my knowledge so far, I can see that, to show this section Magento 2 uses knockout JS(details.js inside magento module-checkout). And I have already extended that JS and it's HTML to show the Product SKU at the same place successfully. I got the product object from the quoteItems and there I can find the Product's SKU, but there is no information for the Product's Stock and QTY available.

Below is the image for the reference:

[image]

Comment: I do have the same problem

Comment: @Milan Pattani how did you get sku in there? I tried but couldnt get the sku there

Comment: @Joey: Override vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/summary/item/details.html file in your extension and add <strong class="product-item-sku" data-bind="text: getSku($parent.item_id)"></strong>, where you want. Then override vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/summary/item/details.js file in your extension and add "getSku" function to it.

Comment: many many thanks for your help. could you help me with adding getsku function in details.js file if Im not troubling you

Comment: @Joey, Give me your details.js code to review and I will update you for the same.

Comment: /**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
/*jshint browser:true jquery:true*/
/*global alert*/
define(
    [
        'uiComponent'
    ],
    function (Component) {
        "use strict";
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'Magento_Checkout/summary/item/details'
            },
            getValue: function(quoteItem) {
                return quoteItem.name;
            }
        });
    }
);







This is all

Comment: @Joey, you will need to add the "getSku" function in the same file as:
getSku: function(itemId) {
                var itemsData = window.checkoutConfig.quoteItemData;
                var prodSku = null;
                itemsData.forEach(function (item) {
                    if(item.item_id == itemId) {
                        prodSku = item.sku;
                    }
                });
                if(prodSku != null) {
                    return 'SKU: ' + prodSku;
                } else {
                    return '';
                }
            },

Comment: @MilanPattani hi, Im not getting what I've expected. I added your code at the end of the file and then after refresh, It showed nothing in summary section. I've put my js file in this link. could you please let me know what is wrong with it?   js file is here,....    https://justpaste.it/1c96e

Comment: @Joey: Corrected your file. Please check https://justpaste.it/1c9v6, it should be working fine now.

Comment: @MilanPattani you are a life saver.thank you sooo much. it worked like a charm

Comment: @Joey: I am glad to hear that. Just up vote the Que. if you think so ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following way:

Create **Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider">
        <plugin name="vendor_module_type_product_customer_data_default_item" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

And now create plugin:

**Vendor/Module/Plugin/Checkout/Model/DefaultConfigProvider.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Checkout\Model;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session as CheckoutSession;

class DefaultConfigProvider
{
    protected $stockItemRepository;
    protected $checkoutSession;

    public function __construct(
        CheckoutSession $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository $stockItemRepository
    ) {
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->stockItemRepository = $stockItemRepository;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function aroundGetConfig(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    ) {
        $result = $proceed();

        if (isset($result['totalsData'])) {
            $totalsData = $result['totalsData'];

            if (isset($totalsData['items'])) {
                $items = $totalsData['items'];

                foreach ($items as &$item) {
                    $item['qty'] = $item['qty'].$this->getAvailableStock($item['item_id']);
                }

                $result['totalsData']['items']=$items;
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }

    public function getAvailableStock($item_id)
    {
        $quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();
        $items = $quote->getAllItems();

        foreach ($items as $item) {
            if ($item->getId() == $item_id) {
                $productStock = $this->stockItemRepository->get($item->getProductId());
                if ($productStock->getQty()) {
                    $availableQty = $productStock->getQty() - $item->getQty();
                    return "  ".__("Available Qty: ") . $availableQty;
                }

                return '';
            }
        }

        return '';
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Sohel, will give it a try and will let you know with the outcome soon.

Comment: That did the trick Sohel, thank you very much for your help. However, I had to customize it bit to match it to my exact requirement. But, your answer helped me much. Thanks again.

Comment: @sohel - Do this work for all type of products?

Comment: @BijalBhavsar, no this exact code will not work with all types of products but, it guided me to achieve it, these will need little change based on type of product's data you are looking for. Let's say for the configurable item "$item->getProductId()" will provide you the parent item ID and not the child one.