# Add Sku and item price in checkout page order summary

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, onepage-checkout, knockoutjs

I need to add product sku(as item code) and item price (as item cost) in `Checkout` page-> Order Summary.
Unlike other pages, checkout page is rendered with `KnockoutJS`, its very hard to add/edit things.

Can someone help me with this please? It should be something like below image.

**Update**

I need to get just sku for the particular product without creating any plugins. I don't know if this is accurate, but I think in default Luma theme sku is available there,[source-[Here,in this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/170990/magento-2-how-to-display-product-available-qty-on-checkout-order-summary)] and sku should available like qty is available. Please help me

[image]

Comment: @KeyurShah it shows answer to create a plugin. Im asking to do this without creating plugin. it should be. but i dont know knockoutJS that much

Comment: Got a Solution if someone needs it, from Milan Pattani(https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/52709)
..........................

Override vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/su‌​mmary/item/details.h‌​tml file in your extension and add <strong class="product-item-sku" data-bind="text: getSku($parent.item_id)"></strong>, where you want. Then override vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/sum‌​mary/item/details.js file in your extension and add "getSku" function to it.

---------------------  modified details.js file here, https://justpaste.it/1c9v6